# Create Swift array from Http GET

Tags: arrays, swift, http

I'm new to swift and am trying to populate a table from an http request.

The array prints just fine within the request but outside it still gives an empty array and doesn't populate the table.

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```html
class affiliates: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
       var tableData = [String]()
    
    
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
     
        
          }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        
        
        // Register custom cell
        var nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell3", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell3")
        
        // Set the URL where we're making the request
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://***************")!)
        
        // Perform the request
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{
            (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?)-> Void in
            
            // Get data as string
            let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(str!)
            
            
            self.tableData.append(str as! String)
            
            
        print(self.tableData)
            
            
            
            }
            
            
            
        );
        
        
        
        
               print(self.tableData)

            
       
        
        
        
        
      
        

        
        
    }
    

    // 2
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        
        
        
        return self.tableData.count
    }
    
    
    // 3
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
        let cell: TblCell3 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3") as! TblCell3
        cell.lblAffiliate.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    // 4
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }
    
    // 5
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }
    


    
    
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your table to reflect the data, you need to call `tableView.reloadData()`